# How to pull data from a row in Access with VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

This might be a stupid question, but I'm still new to Access VBA. I have a form that has a lot of fields on it. I have just created a subform that is pulling data from another table, but I need it to base its pull on data in the main form.

So the main form has *Project Number, Project Type,* and *GroupID* and I want to use that combination to pull the Permit from a secondary table into the subform.

The Primary table is called *PMDBII* and the Secondary table is called *Project_Permit*.

- MAIN FORM: The Primary table is what is displayed in the main form. I also have a list of Permit types in a third table.
- SUBFORM: What I have in the subform are 2 list boxes. One I want to hold the list of *Permits* that are not associated with the current *Project* and the other to hold the list of *Permits* that are associated with it. And then there are two buttons to select additional *Permits* or to remove them.

Forms currently looks like this:

[image: Project form]

So the *Project* that is selected it shows the *Permit* that is associated with it as highlighted.

What I want to do is have the list on the left be a list of all *Permits* that **are not** associated with the *Project* and the list on the right be all *Permits* that **are** associated with the *Project*.

So that it would look something like this:

```
+----------------+--------+
| Federal        | Tribal |
| Power Easement |        |
| Railroad       |        |
| State          |        |
| Township       |        |
+----------------+--------+
```

Then I could select another Permit on the left and click the > button to move it to the right.

The problem is that I don't know how to get the correct data entered into the *Project_Permit* table. I know that I'll need to enter the *Project number, Project Type, GroupID* and *Permit*. I can get the *Permit* it's the rest that I'm having trouble with.

This is what I've got so far:

```vb
Private Sub cmd_Select_Click()
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim ProjectNum As String
    Dim PermitNum As String
    Dim GROUPID As String
    Dim ProjectType As String

    With Me.PERMIT
        PermitNum = .Value
    End With


    SQL = "INSERT INTO pmdb.Project_Permit(Project,Permit,ProjectType,GroupID)" _
           & " Select '" & ProjectNum & "', " & PermitNum & ", " & ProjectType & ", '" & GROUPID & "';"

    CurrentDb.Execute SQL

    Forms![DATASHEET - CAF2].Form!PERMIT.Requery
    Forms![DATASHEET - CAF2].Form!Selected.Requery

End Sub
```

This is on the main form. I don't know how to use this to get the rest of the data that I need to insert the new record.

Comment: You need to populate those with values. You really should use parameterized queries instead of building up a string and executing it. What you have is vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: @SeanLange that is a great suggestion, though I've not done that in Access. I'll give a try if I run into problems I'll post a question about that.

Comment: Had to learn about 'sql injection' https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 says even parameterized data is vulnerable. I have never used dynamic parameterized queries and routinely construct SQL statements in VBA. Never had an issue.

Comment: @June7 parameterized queries are only vulnerable if it being executed as part of a dynamic sql call. Just because you have not yet had a problem do not assume that your code is ok. Not using parameterized queries is negligent at a minimum. It is so simple to use that anything else is just lazy.

Comment: Okay, maybe I should point out I don't use SQL-Server, just Access.

Comment: I am not aware of a working SQL injection example with Access applications. There are some possible examples, but the values in question are coming from bound columns to a form (and they are number type - so in this case no real chance of SQL injection is possible).

Comment: Parameterized queries are not all about SQL injection. You write cleaner code, avoid constant quoting and string interpolation, etc. for readable, maintainable, even DRY-er solutions. Plus you abstract the query statement from data.

Comment: Parameterized queries also escape quotes and double-quotes from literal string delimiters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply reference the main [forms controls](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm) in your append query called from subform. Below also shows how to [parameterize the query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193967.aspx) using querydefs either as a VBA string or saved Access query approach. Of course adjust form and/or control names and param data types.

**VBA String Query Approach**

```
...
Dim qdef as QueryDef

' PREPARE STATEMENT (DEFINES PARAMS AND ADDS THEM AS PLACEHOLDERS)
SQL = "PARAMETERS [ProjectNumParam] TEXT(255), [PermitNumParam] LONG," _
       & "        [ProjectType] TEXT(255), [GROUPIDParam] LONG;" _
       & " INSERT INTO Project_Permit(Project, Permit," _ 
       & "                            ProjectType, GroupID)" _
       & " VALUES ([ProjectNumParam], [PermitNumParam], " _
       & "         [ProjectTypeParam], [GROUPIDParam]);"

' INITIALIZE QUERY OBJECT
Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", SQL)

' BIND VALUES TO PARAMS
qdef![ProjectNumParam] = Forms!mymainform!ProjectNum
qdef![PermitNumParam] = Forms!mysubform!PermitNum
qdef![ProjectTypeParam] = Forms!mymainform!ProjectType
qdef![GROUPIDParam] = Forms!mymainform!GROUPID

' EXECUTE ACTION  
qdef.Execute dbfailOnError

Set qdef = NOthing
```

---

**Saved Query Approach**

SQL *(save as Access stored query, `PARAMETERS` is valid in Access SQL dialect)*

```sql
PARAMETERS [ProjectNumParam] TEXT(255), [PermitNumParam] LONG,
           [ProjectType] TEXT(255), [GROUPIDParam] LONG;
INSERT INTO Project_Permit(Project, Permit, ProjectType, GroupID)
VALUES ([ProjectNumParam], [PermitNumParam], [ProjectTypeParam], [GROUPIDParam])
```

VBA *(reference above query by name)*

```
' INITIALIZE QUERY OBJECT
Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("mySavedQuery")

' BIND VALUES TO PARAMS
qdef![ProjectNumParam] = Forms!mymainform!ProjectNum
qdef![PermitNumParam] = Forms!mysubform!PermitNum
qdef![ProjectTypeParam] = Forms!mymainform!ProjectType
qdef![GROUPIDParam] = Forms!mymainform!GROUPID

' EXECUTE ACTION  
qdef.Execute dbfailOnError

Set qdef = Nothing
```

Comment: This does what I need it to. Thanks! I used the first part the VBA String Query Approach.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help. Good luck on interesting project.